# Gerar texto a partir de formulário

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que ao preencher os campos, eles apareçam na textbox substituindo os valores "NOME DO USUÁRIO", "TIPO DE ADVERTÊNCIA" e "LINK DO TÓPICO"?

```
    Private Sub bemvindo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bemvindo.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Application.ExitThread()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub body_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles body.Paint

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Poste o código que você tem ou que deu problema...O suficiente para que possamos lhe ajudar

Comment: Ja tentou  o método GetValue? 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1'

Comment: Não é nenhum problema. Eu gostaria de saber era como gerar um formulário a partir dos campos que eu preencheria e ao clicar em "Gerar MP de advertência" iria gerar aquele texto de lado. Entendeu? De qualquer forma, adicionei o código atual, mas penso que não vá ser útil em nada.

Comment: Irei ver esse GetValue.

Comment: Não percebi muito bem... mas acho que não é isso.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWsMqOE1o9E - É isto, porem eu queria na textbox e não em um documento word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é o método mais eficiente, mas no meu ponto de vista é um dos melhores.

```
 Dim GeralTF As String = ""
 Dim V As New List(Of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex)
 Dim VR As New List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GeralTF = RichTextBox1.Text

        'O que substituir
        V.Add(New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("{nome}"))
        V.Add(New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("{tipo}"))
        V.Add(New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("{usando}"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Substituir pelo que (em ordem)
        VR.Add(TextBox1.Text) 'Text Box de    nome
        VR.Add(TextBox2.Text) 'Text Box de    tipo
        VR.Add(TextBox3.Text) 'Text Box de    usando


        Dim finalT As String = GeralTF
        Dim i As Int16 = 0
        For Each regexi As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex In V
            finalT = regexi.Replace(finalT, VR(i))
            i += 1
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = finalT
        VR.Clear()
    End Sub
```

> Olá {nome},
>
> Gostaria de testar o programa e bla bla bla do tipo {tipo} usando
>   {usando}, esteja atento.

No Form Load adiciona novos Regex á uma lista, cada Regex é uma String que terá no texto e devera ser substituída por outra na qual sera adicionada a outra lista NA MESMA ORDEM no evento do clique do botão.

Comment: Obs: No texto pode ter quantos {nome} (ou outras strings declaradas) quiser.

Comment: Obs2: usei RichTextBox pois achei melhor para trabalhar com esse tipo de texto do que TextBox comum.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8nnu7o Deu esses erros. Como posso resolver?  / código: http://pastebin.com/RrTcdsJy

Comment: Certo. FIz isso, porem os erros continuam. / código editado: http://pastebin.com/a10H3tkZ

Comment: Bote o código assim: http://pastebin.com/62E9eBkW

Comment: Qualquer outro erro avise.

Comment: Estive aqui testando, porem reparei num pequeno problema. Nós preenchemos tudo certo, clicamos em gerar, até aí tudo bem, tudo certo. Mas quando vamos gerar uma segunda vez, não funciona.

Comment: Desculpe-me esqueçi o  VR.Clear() embaixo do  RichTextBox1.Text = finalT

Comment: Agora sim! Está tudo, obrigado por esclarecer minhas dúvidas. Estou meio que aprendendo VB.net

Answer (score 0):

Vamos, você também pode usar o método .Replace("String Antiga" ou Integer,"String Nova" ou Integer)

---

Veja:

```
Private Sub btnGerarMP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGerarMP.Click
Dim strMP as String
strMP = txtMP.text.Replace("NOME DO USUÁRIO", txtNomeUsuario.text).Replace("TIPO DE ADVERTÊNCIA", txtAdvertencia.text).Replace("LINK DO TÓPICO", txtTopico.text)
```

Espero que seja isso.

Answer (score -1):

```
dim usuario as string = txtUsuario.Text
dim advertencia as string = txtAdvertencia.Text
dim topico as string = txtTopico.Text
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    txtMensagem.Text = "Olá " & usuario & " ," 'Escreva aqui toda sua mensagem, e quando precisar das informações digitadas, use a string.
End Sub
```